Why doesn't double jeopardy apply in this case where a woman was convicted of attempted murder, then manslaughter when the victim died years later?
There's an article in today's news about a woman who pleaded "no contest" to attempted murder in 1985 after allegedly shaking a child and causing him serious injury. In 2019 the child, now grown up, died from those injuries. The woman was indicted and has now pleaded "guilty" to manslaughter.
The Double Jeopardy Clause of the Fifth Amendment to the US Constitution prohibits multiple punishments for the same offense. Since she only committed a single act, I would expect that her 1985 plea and punishment would prevent a second prosecution. Why is that not the case?
Edit: The linked "duplicate" question is about a situation where a person is acquitted at trial but new evidence arose later and they were retried for the same crime.
This question is about a situation where a person pleaded to one crime (attempted murder) and was later indicted for a different crime (manslaughter) arising from the same act.

@Barmar No, double jeopardy applies when you're tried for a crime. For example, it attaches when a jury is sworn in.  Fifth amendment: "nor shall any person be subject for the same offence to be twice put in jeopardy of life or limb"

@Barmar So… attempted murder requires proof of intent while manslaughter does not, and manslaughter requires that the victim was killed while attempted murder does not, so each can be prosecuted and punished separately. Is that the idea?

I don't know what the specific details are in this particular case.

@Robert It's not double jeopardy under the Blockburger test because death of the victim is not an element of attempted murder while death of the victim is an element of manslaughter.

@ohwilleke It looks like Blockburger requires each crime to contain an element not found in the other.

@Robert The second crime has to have an element not found in the first. Manslaughter is not a lesser included offense in attempted murder, it has a separate element.

@Robert See, e.g. People v. Latham, 1994 WL 35556, at *1 (N.Y. Feb. 10, 1994). https://digitalcommons.tourolaw.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2114&context=lawreview

I was under the impression that charging someone with murder (or manslaughter) was standard practice if you've already charged someone with attempted murder and the victim succumbs to their injuries?

@ChellCPlus It is standard practice.

Depending on where this happened, there may be a time limit so if the victim dies “years later” there may be no murder or manslaughter charge at all.

Double jeopardy applies to the same offence, not the same act or omission
Attempted murder and manslaughter are not the same offence.

It's not just the same offense, but it also covers lesser and included offenses. For example, you cannot be prosecuted for attempted murder after a prosecution for murder.

If you committed murder, does that not imply there was no attempted murder? I can understand the same act can be battery and attempted murder, but can it be both murder and attempted murder?

@gnasher729 manslaughter isn’t murder

@gnasher729 You could be charged with murder and attempted murder from the same facts at the same time if, for example, you fire a gun at person A intending to kill them, but instead kill person B because you aim sucks. You are guilty of attempted murder as to person A, and murder as to person B (under the doctrine of transferred intent).
